# Ways to fit a monotonic function to the data?

Tags: interpolation, monotone-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Asked at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167217/) but it seems no one have an idea, so I'm coming again.

Suppose I have 3 data points ($(0, 0), (0 < t_2 < 1, 0 < y_2 < 1), (1, 1))$ and I want to use a monotonic function to interpolate the points. I know that directly fitting a Beta CDF would be a theoretical way (though I'm still finding a way to do so) but is there any alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about $c(t) = ty_2/t_2$ for $ t \leqslant t_2$ and $c(t) = y_2+(1-y_2)(t-t_2)/(1-t_2)$ when $t > t_2$.

Comment: So piecewise linear interpolation hmm... Any global way?

Comment: what do you mean by global?

Comment: One function to go thru all the data points; you suggested using piecewise functions between neighboring data points and I think it's still be pretty nice.

Comment: It may be tricky (I am not sure) to find a single concise expression that always generates an ascending function.  However, functions are perfectly valid even if they cannot be described with a one-line formula.